# "does not live long enough" error when calling `roots` from rust-xcb

Tags: rust, lifetime, lifetime-scoping

I'm trying to use a Cairo surface in xcb-created window. I have a C example as well as Rust XCB and Cairo bindings. I'm almost finished, but this error remains a mystery to me.

My code:

```
fn find_visual<'a>(conn: &'a xcb::Connection, visual: xcb_visualid_t) -> Option<Visualtype<'a>> {
    let setup: Setup<'a> = conn.get_setup();
    for screen in setup.roots() {
        let d_iter: DepthIterator = screen.allowed_depths();
        for depth in d_iter {
            for vis in depth.visuals() {
                if visual == vis.visual_id() {
                    println!("Found visual");
                    return Some(vis)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    None
}
```

I call this as:

```
let visual = find_visual(&conn, screen.root_visual()).unwrap();
```

And gain errors like this:

```
src/main.rs:56:19: 56:24 error: `setup` does not live long enough
src/main.rs:56     for screen in setup.roots() {
                                 ^~~~~
src/main.rs:54:97: 68:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 54:96...
src/main.rs:54 fn find_visual<'a>(conn: &'a xcb::Connection, visual: xcb_visualid_t) -> Option<Visualtype<'a>> {
src/main.rs:55     let setup: Setup<'a> = conn.get_setup();
src/main.rs:56     for screen in setup.roots() {
src/main.rs:57         let d_iter: DepthIterator = screen.allowed_depths();
src/main.rs:58         for depth in d_iter {
src/main.rs:59             for vis in depth.visuals() {
               ...
src/main.rs:55:45: 68:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 55:44
src/main.rs:55     let setup: Setup<'a> = conn.get_setup();
src/main.rs:56     for screen in setup.roots() {
src/main.rs:57         let d_iter: DepthIterator = screen.allowed_depths();
src/main.rs:58         for depth in d_iter {
src/main.rs:59             for vis in depth.visuals() {
src/main.rs:60                 if visual == vis.visual_id() {
               ...
```

And the same errors for `screen` and `depth` variables.

Can someone explain - why "`setup` does not live long enough"? As I understand, `setup` will be destroyed when function `return` Option, and it can be used in function without limitations.

`get_setup()` code:

```
pub fn get_setup(&self) -> Setup {
    unsafe {

        let setup = xcb_get_setup(self.c);
        if setup.is_null() {
            panic!("NULL setup on connection")
        }
        mem::transmute(setup)
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird, looking at rust-xcb's source I can't find any lifetime annotations; in particular, the Setup struct doesn't have any.

Comment: @SebastianRedl As I see lifetimes exists http://rtbo.github.io/rust-xcb/src/xcb/xproto.rs.html#1516

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the outdated Aatch repo.

Comment: I seems like returned vis depends on previously binded variables. When I remove `Some(vis)` compile become success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the lifetime annotations of the bindings are faulty. Here's `roots()`:

```
impl<'a> Screen<'a> {
    pub fn roots(&self) -> ScreenIterator {
        unsafe {
            xcb_setup_roots_iterator(self.ptr)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that because there are no annotations on the function, this is implicitly annotated as

```
impl<'a> Screen<'a> {
    pub fn <'b> roots(&'b self) -> ScreenIterator<'b> {
        unsafe {
            xcb_setup_roots_iterator(self.ptr)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is wrong. The returned `ScreenIterator` needs to be explicitly annotated with lifetime `'a` instead, which is the lifetime of the underlying connection, and XCB appears to have the convention that all the pointers it hands out are bound by lifetime to the lifetime of the connection (see the comment for the wrapper type `base::StructPtr`. This means the generator scripts need to be adjusted to account for this. You should file an issue with the crate.

**upd from requestor:**
@SebastianRedl was right. Problem is in unset lifetimes in xcb crate for all functions which returns Iterators. Next lifetime changes in rust-xcb crate allows to compile code successfully:

```
impl<'a> Setup<'a> {
    pub fn roots(&self) -> ScreenIterator<'a> {
        unsafe {
             xcb_setup_roots_iterator(self.ptr)
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Depth<'a> {
    pub fn visuals(&self) -> VisualtypeIterator<'a> {
        unsafe {
            xcb_depth_visuals_iterator(self.ptr)
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Screen<'a> {
    pub fn allowed_depths(&self) -> DepthIterator<'a> {
        unsafe {
            xcb_screen_allowed_depths_iterator(self.ptr)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've change the xcb ffi generator and gain  an "error: lifetime name `'a` shadows a lifetime name that is already in scope". It seems like we can't use the same lifetime name as in impl<'a> Screen<'a>

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't declare a new lifetime, but use the existing one.  So it should look like:
    "pub fn roots(&'a self) -> ScreenIterator<'a> { ... }", not "pub fn roots<'a>(...)".